# What is the point of putting a Rock on the comm with the Mantis?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

A couple times now, I've encountered a Mantis ship decorated with Rock body parts.  If I have a Rock crew member, I am given a blue option to put him on the comm with the mantis ship.  Every time I do this, there is still a fight and I get no obvious rewards increase at the end.

Usually a blue option avoids a fight or gives some other kind of benefit, but what does this one do for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be one, except for the unique text that occurs.  I've never had anything happen differently after choosing this option.

The [FTL Wikia](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Mantis_Ship_Rock_body_parts) lists this event and the various outcomes, which lines up with what we've observed.  However, they also note that this event is sometimes buggy and may be incomplete.

Comment: Ah, I looked on the [main events page](http://ftlwiki.com/wiki/Events) and it is not listed.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot, yeah, that's the "official" wiki, there's also a Wikia site, which is where I found it.

Comment: I love it when the unofficial wiki is better than the official one...